# how to open all shortcuts files from a directory with chromium-browser in one command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, gnome-terminal

On ubuntu 16.04, i have a directory with these files :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user0 user0  86 jui  7 21:32 vim html picker.url
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user0 user0 104 jui  7 21:32 cocoonjs build android apk.url
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user0 user0  61 jui  7 21:32 Simple Modal Window - Codepad.url
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user0 user0  96 jui  7 21:32 cocoon.js android build apk+++.url
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user0 user0  44 jui  7 21:32 CodePen - Front End Developer Playground & Code Editor in the Browser (1).url
```

The file "vim html picker.url" have this information :

```
-->  cat vim\ html\ picker.url 

[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://github.com/KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim/blob/master/README.md
```

what i want to do is open all of theses files from this directory in tab in my chromium-browser.

i have tried this in my gnome-terminal :

```
chromium-browser *.*
```

but chrome open the text information : URL=https://github.com/KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim/blob/master/README.md and not the url itself :https://github.com/KabbAmine/vCoolor.vim/blob/master/README.md.

wich command allow my desired behaviour ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't appear to be programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep "^URL=" *.url | cut -d= -f2 | xargs chromium-browser`
should do the trick.

Explanation:

- `grep "^URL=" *.url` - cut the line beginning with `URL=` from each file ending in `.url`
- `cut -d= -f2` - split each remaining line into parts delimited by '=' and output the second and all subsequent parts (i.e. the part after the first '=')
- `xargs chromium-browser` - use the list of URLs as arguments to chromium.

Comment: grep "^URL=" *.url | cut -d= -f2 | xargs chromium-browser